# Does the AVPlayerViewController automatically come with a AVPlayer object?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, viewcontroller, avplayerviewcontroller

New to swift and the view controller paradigm.  Would like to know if ViewControllers automatically come with the objects it describes for example, does avplayerviewcontroller automatically come with an avplayer object ready to be used or do we still need to create an avplayer object?  Another example could be uitableviewcontroller, does it automatically come with a tableview object or do we need to create it after creating a cocoa touch class that subclasses uitableviewcontroller.

Here is some example code that compiles where I didn't necessarily create an avplayer object but it seems like that object was already ready to be used through a property called 'player':

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class MeetTheAuthorViewController: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //playBackgroundMusic("bensound-jazzyfrenchy-castlesbackground.mp3")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    }

    func btn_clicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Do something
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "videoSegue"
        {
            //set up the player
            let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "The Atlanta Goat_ Part One-HD", withExtension: "mp4")
            let videoViewController = segue.destination as! AVPlayerViewController
            videoViewController.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
            videoViewController.player?.play()


        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. XYFeatureViewControllers are convenience `UIViewController` subclasses. For example `UITableViewController` inherits from `UIViewController`, assumes its `view` is of type `UITableView` and already conforms to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.

Often they offer default implementations for delegate methods and thus "just work" right away.

In case of a `UITableView`, I would recommend to use a custom `UIViewController` an add `UITableView`(s) yourself to have the full flexibility.

For Example, `UITableViewController` has the `UITableView` as root view, so if you want to make the tableView smaller on screen later on (example), you can't.

In your custom viewController, the tableView would be a subView of the rootView, so resizing it or adding a second one next to it would not be a problem.

Comment: So you're saying they automatically come with the pre-destined object such as a tableview already having a tableview object ready for use through a property without having to create one.  In that case, if we wanted to have two tableview objects inside a uitableviewcontroller, we'd have to instantiate a new tableview object for the second one? @shallowThought

Comment: "So you're saying they automatically come with the pre-destined object such as a tableview already having a tableview object ready for use through a property without having to create one": Yes